# A simple Cosine similarity

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net, math.net

- Vectors contains one column, m rows : each row contains an array of n floats;
- I want to have a m x n matrix, transpose it and do there product
- I'm using C#

Also, I read this from official documentation https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html

> "For example, if you have a collection of vectors, consider to store
> them in a list or array of vectors, not in a matrix (unless you need
> matrix operations, of course)."

So please what's the optimized way to achieve this with Math.net.numerics? Thanks in advance

#UPDATE

I'm getting this Error

```
CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<float[]>' to 'float[]'
```

With this code :

```
IEnumerable<float[]> Vectors = predictions.GetColumn<float[]>("Features");
var x = new M.DenseMatrix(1, Vectors.Count(), Vectors);
```

Comment: optimized compared to _what_? also: _code as text_, please.

Comment: - Optimized in absolute

- (Code as text will lose variable type information)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann do you have any answer?

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
var Matrix = M.SparseMatrix.OfColumnArrays(Vectors);
```

Details :

```
public Matrix<T> SparseOfColumnArrays(IEnumerable<T[]> columns);
```

is expecting the same type of vector with T=float, so it worked. I suggest you read the library methods from your IDE. 2- As the matrix is not dense I switched to Sparse.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! Can you please try and explain *why* this fixes the error and what was the mistake in the original code in the question?

Comment: `public Matrix<T> SparseOfColumnArrays(IEnumerable<T[]> columns);`is expecting the same type of vector with T=float, so it worked. I suggest you read the library methods from your IDE. 2- As the matrix is not dense I switched to Sparse.

Comment: Please put the explanation in the answer :) Thanks!

Comment: How do you feel now? @omajid :) TBH I'm not happy with what's going on here. I had a real issue that I resolved and even shared my solution, so people can save time. But I don't know why this post is getting -4 score? It's really unfair and discouraging

Comment: I think part of that is the StackOverflow culture and expectations. People look at answers and downvote (or worse, propose for deletion) if the answer is just code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300694/what-to-do-with-code-only-answers-in-low-quality-posts-queue and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers. Adding an explanation will help get you a higher score!

Comment: This is giving power to mindless bureaucratic "bots" or worse cyborgs. I detailed my answer, edited my post many times just for the sake of helping others. I showed my good will. On the other hand, I had no added value from all this as I found the solution my self, and wasted time/energy dealing with people's fantasms here. I'm new here, and this experience is just frustrating, worse communication is part of it. @omajid